# jenkins in docker - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm running https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/blueocean/ in docker.  Trying to build a docker image in jenkins.

but i get the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

clearly the jenkins version in docker does not have access to the docker binary.

I confirmed this by,

```
docker exec -it db4292380977 bash
docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

"db4292380977" is the running container. It shows the same error.

Question:

- how do I allow access to docker in the jenkins container?

Answer (score 12):

The docker client is installed on the `jenkinsci/blueocean` image, but not the daemon. Docker client will use the daemon (by default via the socket `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`). Docker client needs a Docker daemon in order to work, you can read [Docker Architecture](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/docker-overview/#docker-architecture) for more info.

What you can do:

## Use docker-in-docker (DinD) image

[Library Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) provides a way to run a Docker daemon in Docker, you can then use it from another container. For example, using plain docker CLI:

```
docker run --name docker-dind --privileged -d docker:stable-dind
docker run --name jenkins --link=docker-dind -d jenkinsci/blueocean
docker exec jenkins docker -H docker-dind images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Docker daemon runs in `docker-dind` container and can be reached using the same hostname. You just need to provide the docker client with the daemon host (`-H docker-dind` in the example, you can also use `DOCKER_HOST` env variable as described in [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/)).

## Mount host machine `/var/run/docker.sock` in your container

As described by [@Herman Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055631/5465973) answer:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --user root \
     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Comment: Any idea how to merge the dind container with jenkins helm chart installation on kubernetes cluster ?!

Answer (score 5):

You need to mount your local `/var/run/docker.sock` and run the container as `root` user

**NOTE:** this might be a security flaw so be careful who has access to the jenkins container

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --user root \
     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkinsci/blueocean
```

you will be able to execute docker inside the container

```
➜  ~  docker exec -it gracious_agnesi bash                                                                                              
bash-4.4# docker ps                                                                                                                     
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        
       NAMES                                                                                                                            
c4dc85b0d88c        jenkinsci/blueocean   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   18 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000
/tcp   gracious_agnesi
```

Comment: I am using windows with admin rights and used this command to run docker with blueocean. But I am getting error failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"


docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro jenkinsci/blueocean

Answer (score 1):

Just only try to do the same command but with sudo in the beginning

For example

```
sudo docker images
sudo docker exec -it db4292380977 bash
```

To avoid use sudo in the future you should run this command in Unix O.S

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <your-user>
```

Change  for the user that you are using at this moment. Remember to log out and back in for this to take effect! More information about Docker installation click [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-repository)

Comment: remember to install `sudo` inside the docker container, jenkins image doesn't come with sudo pre-installed